# Find indexes of substrings inside a cell in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I need to identify the indexes of approximate occurrences substrings inside a cell. So for instance:

```
C = {'Hong Kong (China)', 'Canada', 'Panama', 'Hong Kong (China)'};.
```

I need to find inside C, all strings having the words of

```
string2search = "Hong Kong";
```

and give something like:

```
ans = [1 0 0 1]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Define "approximate matching". Substring, maybe?

Comment: Yes substring is correct

Comment: Oh, now I see you had "substring" in the title :-)

Comment: I actually updated it after your suggestion! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if `string2search` is a substring of each string in `C`: you can use [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) within [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
result = cellfun(@(s) ~isempty(strfind(s, string2search)), C);
```

If case is unimportant, apply [`lower`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/lower.html):

```
result = cellfun(@(s) ~isempty(strfind(lower(s), lower(string2search))), C);
```